# Why when making object to rotate around another object with setting a radius the rotating around object is not on the exact radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The rotating around object is a cube. the target it's rotating around is a sphere.
The radius is drawn around the sphere.

In the first screenshot the radius is 1 the cube is half almost half on the radius line. the pink line.

Maybe in this case it's fine because the cube is touching or very close to the sphere.
Maybe i should do somehow that if the radius is small and the rotating object around the target touch each other colliders then move the rotating object a bit more on the radius like in this screenshot :

[image: radius is 1]

And this screenshot when i changed the radius to 5 now the cube is not no the pink line at all :

[image: radius is 5]

This is where i'm setting the radius and the making the object that rotate around to move to that position on the Z :

Line 43 :

```
radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z + dc.xRadius);
```

xRadius is 5 in this screenshot. The cube is moving to the radius on the z but too far. the cube is not exactly on the pink line.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float rotatingSpeed;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public Vector3 axis;
    public bool randomHeight;
    public float setRandomHeight = 1;
    public float radius;
    public DrawCircle dc;

    private float lastRadius;
    private bool move = false;
    private float t = 0.0f;
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;
    private float prevHeight;
    private Vector3 radiusPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (dc != null)
        {
            lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            radius = dc.xRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            lastRadius = radius;
        }
        move = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            if (dc != null)
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z + dc.xRadius);
                radius = dc.xRadius;
            }
            else
            {
                radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, target.position.z + radius);
            }
        }

        if (move == false)
        {
            if (target != null)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(target.position, axis, rotatingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (randomHeight)
            {
                t += Time.deltaTime;

                if (t > delay)
                {
                    prevHeight = setRandomHeight;
                    setRandomHeight = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
                    t = 0;
                }

                var tt = transform.position;
                tt.y = Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, setRandomHeight, t);
                transform.position = tt;
            }
        }

        if (dc != null)
        {
            if (lastRadius != dc.xRadius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastRadius != radius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = radius;
            }
        }

        if (move)
        {
            if (transform.position != radiusPosition)
            {
                float step = movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                    radiusPosition, step);
            }
            else
            {
                move = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving along a circular path in 2d requires 2 position components to be modified.

Looking down at the circle (along the Y axis), the position components that need to be modified are (X, Z).

```
void Update()
{
    angle += rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (angle > 180)
        angle -= 360;
    
    if (angle < -180)
        angle += 360;
    
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        origin.position.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, 0, 
        origin.position.z + Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius
    );
}
```